# How can I use angular 2 packages with angular 4?

Tags: angular

I am interested in an angular2 package.
I am running @angular/common@4.0.2.

When I try to install it, this is the message I have:

```
peerinvalid Peer angular2package@0.0.1-alpha.1 wants @angular/common@^2.0.0
```

I could downgrade my angular to 2.

But I thought Angular 2 and 4 or Angular.io or Angular in short were all compatible and same architecture?

How can I use this angular 2 compatible package with 4?

Comment: Have you tried ignoring npm and just giving it a go?

Comment: I didn't bypass npm yet. How do you ignore npm then?

Comment: You just... ignore it. You don't need to "bypass" it, just keep writing the software without taking any notice.

Comment: Oh ok. The package is actually installed. I will see if it is broken. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Updating to 4 is as easy as updating your Angular dependencies to the latest version, and double checking if you want animations. This will work for most use cases.

On Linux/Mac:

```
npm install @angular/{common,compiler,compiler-cli,core,forms,http,platform-browser,platform-browser-dynamic,platform-server,router,animations}@latest typescript@latest --save
```

On Windows:

```
npm install @angular/common@latest @angular/compiler@latest @angular/compiler-cli@latest @angular/core@latest @angular/forms@latest @angular/http@latest @angular/platform-browser@latest @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@latest @angular/platform-server@latest @angular/router@latest @angular/animations@latest typescript@latest --save
```